# React Native Expo Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am just starting out in React Native and do not fully understand the following.

I am using Expo, Android and Firebase(Free version).  I'd like to setup push notifications and followed a tutorial online and actually got it working!

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2zoM_QWGY0

In the tutorial the author used the following method to send a push notification from the Expo documenation;

[image]

What I would like to clarify is - is it correct to say this will not work if the application is installed on the device i.e. not running via the Expo app on Android device?

Or will this work in a real life scenario when a user downloads the APK/app from the Google PlayStore for example?

Sorry for the simple question but cannot seem to find anything that answers this question specifically.

Send notification function in my code;

```
sendPushNotification = () => {
let response = fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify( {
    to: 'I have the device token here',
    sound: 'default',
    title: 'Demo',
    body: 'Demo Notification'
  })
})
```

};

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, if you want to check it you can easily generate the APK build using the expo client to test it on your own phone.

Comment: Oh really? I just assumed I needed some kind of server side code as this setup seemed a little 'easy'. I do have 2 physical android devices so I will install it and test it.  Thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think normally people use a service like this one rather than making their own push notification server. I'm going to check expo docs to calrify though.

Comment: I believe in your case firebase is acting as your "server side code" and so thats why you haven't needed to do extra steps. 

I recommend checking https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/ for info on expo push notifications.

Comment: That would make sense I guess.  I am pushing the push notification token to my firebase and getting it when I need it then using the fetch to actually push the notification message to the intended user.  Thanks for the link - will read through.  Thanks again.